# How to get track ID from URL using the SoundCloud API

Tags: url, soundcloud

How can I get a track ID from a track URL using the SoundCloud API?

Comment: Related, for those who are seeking to do the inverse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495775/get-soundcloud-url-for-a-track-using-only-its-id

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You didn't specify a language in your question, so I'm just going to provide a high-level answer.

Use the `resolve` endpoint. I'm using this URL as an example:

https://soundcloud.com/msmrsounds/ms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix

```
HTTP GET: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fmsmrsounds%2Fms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix&client_id=[your_client_id]
```

The resulting JSON:

```
{
  "status": "302 - Found",
  "location": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/147986343.json?client_id=[YOUR client_id]"
}
```

That numerical value is the `track_id`. You can just stop here or hit that endpoint you just got back for more information:

```
{
  "kind": "track",
  "id": 90787841,
  "created_at": "2013/05/05 00:15:40 +0000",
  "user_id": 7853935,
  "duration": 188333,
  "commentable": true,
  "state": "finished",
  "original_content_size": 35031144,
  "last_modified": "2014/09/30 05:53:10 +0000",
  "sharing": "public",
  "tag_list": "MSMR CHVRCHES \"Secondhand Rapture\" Remix Hurricane",
  "permalink": "ms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix",
  "streamable": true,
  "embeddable_by": "all",
  "downloadable": true,
  "purchase_url": null,
  "label_id": null,
  "purchase_title": null,
  "genre": "",
  "title": "MS MR - Hurricane (CHVRCHES remix)",
  "description": "MS MR - Hurricane (CHVRCHES remix)\r\n\r\n\r\n",
  "label_name": "",
  "release": "",
  "track_type": "",
  "key_signature": "",
  "isrc": "",
  "video_url": null,
  "bpm": null,
  "release_year": null,
  "release_month": null,
  "release_day": null,
  "original_format": "wav",
  "license": "all-rights-reserved",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841",
  "user": {
    "id": 7853935,
    "kind": "user",
    "permalink": "msmrsounds",
    "username": "MSMR",
    "last_modified": "2014/08/04 09:03:56 +0000",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/7853935",
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/msmrsounds",
    "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000037198343-2lptmy-large.jpg?86347b7"
  },
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/msmrsounds/ms-mr-hurricane-chvrches-remix",
  "artwork_url": null,
  "waveform_url": "https://w1.sndcdn.com/56LCadzDEBZn_m.png",
  "stream_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841/stream",
  "download_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841/download",
  "playback_count": 1672227,
  "download_count": 18494,
  "favoritings_count": 20426,
  "comment_count": 464,
  "attachments_uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841/attachments",
  "policy": "ALLOW"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much... BTW, it is in PHP. I just figured it out using json_decode() function.

Comment: Unfortunately, SoundCloud closed registration to their API around July 2017. This method is only valid for those who registered before then.

Comment: For further reference regarding API registration, as [mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47971364/924299) by [Hamza Zymawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6531160/hamza-zymawy), the [application form](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/api-sign-up-changes) currently links [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform), where it says "we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time".

Answer (score 9):

Since the SoundCloud API is indefinitely not accepting new registrations, here's one alternative solution. This URL will provide you with a wide/short embedded player:

`https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=` *+ URL of track*

Example: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/chrisbjerken/picking-up-the-pieces

This works for both a single track or a playlist.

Answer (score 4):

So my final code looks like this. Thank you guys for the help to get this working.

```
include_once('../Services/Soundcloud.php'); 
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET');
$track_url=$_POST['trackurl'];
$track_url=str_replace("https://soundcloud.com/USERNAME/","",$track_url);
$track = json_decode($client->get("tracks/".$track_url));    
$track_id=$track->id;
echo $track_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In The Meantime Writing This Answer The CLIENT_ID Is Close

> Due to the high amount of requests recently received, we will no longer be processing API application requests at this time. We are working to re-evaluate our process to make it more efficient.

See [Here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfNxc82RJuzC0DnISat7n4H-G7IsPQIdaMpe202iiHZEoso9w/closedform)

I Solved This Issue With My Laravel Project Like This

first I Made This Function To Get The Real Content

```
    public function getLessonUrl($lessonId = null)
{
    //Get the SoundCloud URL
    $validUrl = 'https://soundcloud.com/al-hazme';
    $result = stripos($lessonId, $validUrl);

    if (strpos($lessonId, $validUrl) !== false) {
        //Get the JSON data details with embed code from SoundCloud oEmbed
        $getValues = @file_get_contents('http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=js&url=' . $lessonId . '&amp;color=%234274e3&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;show_teaser=true&show_artwork');

        if ($getValues === false) {
            return 'حدث خطأ اثناء تحميل الدرس نرجو منك التأكد من اتصال الانترنيت لديك او حدث الصفحة';
        }
        //Clean the Json to decode

        $decodeiFrame = substr($getValues, 1, -2);

        //json decode to convert it as an array

        $jsonObj = json_decode($decodeiFrame);

        //echo $jsonObj->html;

        $lessons = str_replace('height="400"', 'height="90"', $jsonObj->html);

        return $lessons;
    } else {
        return 'لايوجد استماع لهذا الدرس';
    }

}
```

Then I Made Another Function To Crap The Id Using Str Facade Methods

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    public function soundCloudId($url) {


    $do         = $lesson->getLessonUrl($lesson->url_link);
    $getTrickId = Str::after($do,'tracks%2F');
    $substr     = Str::substr($getTrickId,0,9);

     echo $substr = // 367893857
     }
```

It May Help Or Give You Clue

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda late but i faced the same issue yesterday and found a new (undocumented) endpoint that you can use.

```
https://api-widget.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=SOUNDLCOUD_URL&format=json&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

You can find your `CLIENT_ID` by looking at the Network Inspector in the DevTools and select the XHR filter while browsing the SoundCloud website.

I think this is sufficient until the official APIs are usable again.

Comment: i get a 404 when i access this page...

Comment: @tubbo probably because of the latest api security changes https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/security-updates-api.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with PHP; may be a bit hacky and not be the most efficient but it works for me and doesn't require the (currently inaccessible) API.

```
function getTrackId($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ));
    $soundCloudResponse = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $scDocument = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $scDocument->loadHTML(str_replace('\"', '"', $soundCloudResponse));
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    try {
        $metaNodes = $scDocument->getElementsByTagName('meta');
        foreach($metaNodes as $metaNode) {
            if($metaNode->getAttribute('property') === "twitter:app:url:googleplay") {
                return explode(':', $metaNode->getAttribute('content'))[2];
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```