# Get Soundcloud URL for a track using only its ID

Tags: soundcloud

I've inherited a database of Soundcloud IDs and would like to build a page linking to each track on Soundcloud. Is it possible to link to a track on the Soundcloud website using only its ID e.g.

```
http://www.soundcloud.com/tracks/{trackId}
```

The website seems to use the format:

```
http://www.soundcloud.com/{user}/{trackname}
```

but I don't have either of those.

Answer (score 11):

You can scrape it from the "widget" URL

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{trackId}

contains a link element

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{canonicalURI}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way to do this is to use the API. With a track number, you can call

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/12345678.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

This returns a JSON object with a `permalink_url` property which gives you the full url including the user and track name.

See the [API tracks documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) for more details.

Comment: Where do I find my client ID to add to the end of that url?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to register an app at https://soundcloud.com/you/apps.

Then use the API to return a JSON object of the track using the track ID and your client ID.

e.g. (using jQuery) …

`$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/405726.json?client_id=XXXX",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});`

Where XXX is your Client ID.

Comment: Unfortunately, SoundCloud closed registration to their API around July 2017. This method is only valid for those who registered before then.