# Soundcloud track url from id

Tags: soundcloud

How do I make a direct link to the actual song on soundcloud given only its id?

example:

`9456836` => `https://soundcloud.com/rylegit/ry-legit-the-sweety-man-unsigned`

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495775/get-soundcloud-url-for-a-track-using-only-its-id), but I would like to know if it is directly possible without having to call the API.

What I'm trying to achieve is something along the lines of:

`www.soundcloud.com/9456836`
or
`www.soundcloud.com/track/9456836`

kinda like you can do with youtube: `youtu.be/TeDQvHMC5w4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, it's a bit hacky but it gets the job done:

`https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F9456836`

`"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F" + id`