# How to get json for soundcloud without type

Tags: php, soundcloud

I get JSON from the Soundcloud API by using code in section【A】.

But I want to get it without using `$type`, like in code【B】.

In other words, I want to get that information by only giving `$target`.

What should I do?

```
$r = soundcloud_responce();
var_dump( $r );

function soundcloud_responce(){

    $client_id = 'xxx'; 
    $type = 'tracks';
    $q = 'words';

    // code【A】
    // If I have $type, So this process ok.
    $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/";
    $url .= $type;
    $url .= "?client_id=$client_id";    
    $url .= "&q=$q";

    // code【B】
    // I want to do same process with $target but without $type
    $target = "https://soundcloud.com/accountname/trackname";
    $target = str_replace('https://soundcloud.com/', '', $target);
    $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/";
    $url .= $target;
    $url .= "?client_id=$client_id";        

    // curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = [
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($res);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $json;
}
```

(Add 2020-02-21-09:38 @Tokyo)

I tried this code【C】but this also failed.

```
    // code【C】
    // I tried with oembed but this also failed.
    $target = "https://soundcloud.com/accountname/trackname";
    $url = 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url='.$target;
```

(Add 2020-02-21-10:12 @Tokyo)

I tried this code【D】but this also failed.

```
    // code【D】
    // I tried with resolve but this also failed.
    $target = "https://soundcloud.com/accountname/trackname";
    $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=$target&client_id=$client_id";
```

Comment: I believe you need to use the ["tracks" endpoint](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) to get track information. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I want to get from only the URL.
Because my website user don't know the type, So He input just URL.

Comment: It looks like you could hardcode the endpoint, something like `$url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/$target?client_id=$client_id"`. Would that work?

Comment: The URL entered is not necessarily tracks.That may be tracks or may be user and playlists

Comment: Ok, I see. So you need a way to detect what's being requested based on the URL?

Comment: I add to (Add 2020-02-21-09:38), but this also failed.Help! Somebody help me!

Comment: That's definitely right. I want to get that json from only URL.

Comment: You might find the [`resolve`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) endpoint helpful: "The resolve resource allows you to lookup and access API resources when you only know the SoundCloud.com URL." It supports users, tracks, playlists (sets), and apps.

Comment: Indeed, if you check it, it seems to be "soundcloud.com/username/trackname", so I can distinguish users and tracks. But playlists and albums were equally "soundcloud.com/username/sets/playlistsname" or "soundcloud.com/username/sets/albumsname" , So I can't tell the difference.

Comment: I think playlists and albums are both considered [sets](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#creating-sets). I'm not sure they are distinguishable.

Comment: Oh! "resolve" seems to be possible.I don't know it. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good. For reference, also see [How to get track ID from URL using the SoundCloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290246/924299).

Comment: I add to (Add 2020-02-21-10:12 @Tokyo), but this also failed.I will try that question out next time.

Comment: What went wrong? What was the response? Did you get an error?

Comment: Sorry,I had made an innocent mistake. code【E】is successed! I appreciate your assistance :)

Comment: @koyubin you should post code `E` into an answer and remove it from the question, in order to adhere to the common Q & A style of this site (it's no problem to answer your own questions).

Comment: @showdev I see. I posted it.Thank you for your continued support.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code【E】this is successful!

Thank you for giving me good advice, @showdev.

```
    // code【E】
    // this is successful!
    $target = "https://soundcloud.com/accountname/trackname";
    $target = urlencode($target);
    $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=$target&client_id=$client_id";
```